# Removing GRUB removed option to boot from USB

Tags: grub, grub2

I have a laptop running windows 10.

Using an Ubuntu live USB, I installed a bootable Ubuntu system to another USB. After creating this and booting into it, when I went to reboot my computer without the USBs plugged in, I got a GRUB prompt. I didn't want that, since I don't actually have Ubuntu installed to the hard disk of the laptop, so I used these instructions to get rid of it:

https://www.binaryera.com/2020/08/RemoveGrubFromWindow10.html

Problem now is that the option to boot from USB is missing from the BIOS.

Any idea how this went wrong and how I can fix it?

Answer (score 0):

The instructions you followed do not manipulate the BIOS/UEFI in
any way, so the problem is not related to that in any way.

I would suggest:

- Verify that the USB is indeed bootable
- If you suspect the BIOS of being defective, download its latest
  version *from your manufacturer* and install it
  (even if you have the same version already installed).
  For safety, remove first any BIOS passwords and undo Bitlocker
  if enabled.

Comment: I'm certain the USB is bootable and I don't suspect the BIOS because I successfully booted the USB previously. What exactly are those instructions doing, so I know how to describe my issue better?

Comment: Removing the UEFI bootloader of an unwanted OS from the EFI partition. This partition is not part of the firmware,  only used by it.